# C++ Template no match for operator<

Tags: c++, templates, operators, operator-keyword

I've seen questions similar to this, but haven't found a solution that worked on my problem, so I was hoping I could get some help.

I want to pass a class as an argument to a function with template parameters (For this example I just want it to compile, so nvm that it doesn't make sense with `return true` in operators). I figured this way in the following code would work:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    bool operator>(const T&) const { 
        return true;
    }  

    bool operator<(const T&) const { 
        return true;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename S> 
vector<T> between_interval(T* start, T* end, const S& low, const S& high){
    vector<T> vec;
    for ( ; start != end; start++) {
        if (low < *start && *start < high)
            vec.push_back(* start);
    }
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    double v1[] = {1.23, 4.56, 7.89, -10, 4};
    MyClass<double> k1;
    MyClass<double> k2;
    vector<double> res = between_interval(v1, v1 + 3, k1, k2);
    for (auto x : res)
        cout << x << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

I get the following error(s):

```
u4.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::vector<T> between_interval(T*, T*, const S&, const S&) [with T = double; S = MyClass<double>]’:
u4.cpp:39:55:   required from here
u4.cpp:28:36: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘double’ and ‘const MyClass<double>’)
     if (low < *start && *start < high)
```

I realize passing K1 and K2 won't make sense as it is at the moment, but the compiler doesn't mention this, it complains about not having a match for `operator<`, so my main question is why? Is it too general with a template argument in `operator<`? Is there any other way to make the operators work but without using the templates?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    bool operator>(const T&) const { 
        return true;
    }  

    bool operator<(const T&) const { 
        return true;
    }
};
```

and

```
MyClass <double> k1;
double d = 4.2;
```

you might do

- `k1 < d`
- `k1 > d`

but you do

- `d < k1` (with `*start < high`)

you have to implement that operator too or change the code to use the provided operator.

Answer (score 4):

Because your `operator <` is a member function it expects the left hand operand to be of the class type.  That is fine for `low < *start` but in `*start < high` you have a `double` as the left hand operand.

You will either need to provide a free function that takes a double as the first parameter or make your class convertible to a double (or `T`).

Answer (score 2):

Member operators always use the left operand as `this` and the right operand as the operator argument. That means your comparison operators will only work when the `MyClass` is on the left of the comparison. The quick fix is to change the line `if (low < *start && *start < high)` to `if (low < *start && high > *start)` to put the `MyClass` instance on the left side of each comparison. The cleaner solution is to provide free operators which take a `T` on the left side and a `MyClass<T>` on the right side. For example :

```
template<typename T>
bool operator>(const T& p_left, const MyClass<T> & p_right) {
    return p_right < p_left;
}

template<typename T>
bool operator<(const T& p_left, const MyClass<T> & p_right) {
    return p_right > p_left;
}
```